# Indenting Format-Table output in PowerShell scripts

Tags: powershell, indentation

How can I indent output from the [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Format-Table) cmdlet to a specific column?

I have:

```
> $SomeValues | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders
A    1
B    2
C    3
```

But I'd like:

```
    A    1
    B    2
    C    3
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your answers. They helped me figure out how to do what I wanted using *calculated properties*. The `Expression` must be one less than the amount of indent, due to the automatic single character space between columns in the table.

If you're using the `-AutoSize` flag:

```
Write-Host "Not indented"
Write-Host "    Indented"
$a = @{ Aa = 1; Bbb = 2; Cccc = 300}
$a | Format-Table -Property @{Expression="   "},Name,Value -AutoSize -HideTableHeaders
```

If you're not using the `-AutoSize` flag:

```
Write-Host "Not indented"
Write-Host "    Indented"
$a = @{ Aa = 1; Bbb = 2; Cccc = 300}
$a | Format-Table -Property @{Expression={}; Width=3},Name,Value -HideTableHeaders
```

The output looks like:

```
Not indented
    Indented

    Bbb      2
    Aa       1
    Cccc   300
```

Comment: @SalvatoreDiFazio: You mean in the number's column? That's the default way PowerShell prints numbers. It's useful because then all the decimal places are lined up for easy comparison.

Comment: In my case I have a lot of '-' char and the information are at the right of my powershell console

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
PS> $a = @{A=1; B=2; C=3}
PS> $a.GetEnumerator() | %{ "{0,10}{1,5}" -f $_.key, $_.value }
         A    1
         B    2
         C    3
```

Comment: Close, but I'd prefer that both columns be left-aligned. I tried your example and the first column became right-aligned.

Comment: $a.GetEnumerator()| % { "{0,5}{1,5}" -f $_.key,$_.value}

Comment: What is the syntax after the pipe called? I'd like to read about it.

Comment: it is .Net format specifier syntax. One example, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ksz8yb7(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

There's another way that doesn't require creating an additional column.  You can simply take the normal output from the **Format-Table** command, use **Out-String** to convert it to a string array, and then use **ForEach-Object** to print out each string with padding.  Here's an example using Get-Process.

```
$indent = "    "
(Get-Process svchost) | Format-Table -Property Id, ProcessName | Out-String -Stream | ForEach-Object {Write-Output "$indent$_"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$SomeValues | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders -AutoSize
```

Comment: You mean -AutoSize? That has nothing to do with the question, that option just changes column widths.

Comment: Aah..My bad. I misread that. You can use format specifiers in that case and not Format-Table

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can use ft and -autosize

```
 $a= @{A=1;B=2;C=3}
 $a.getenumerator() | ft blah,name,value -hidetableheaders -auto

      A        1
      B        2
      C        3
```

Answer (score 0):

For a generic solution

```
 function Indent-ConsoleOutput($output, $indent=4){
    if(!($output -eq $null)){
        if(!( $indent -is [string])){
            $indent = ''.PadRight($indent)
        }
        $width = (Get-Host).UI.RawUI.BufferSize.Width - $indent.length
        ($output| out-string).trim().replace( "`r", "").split("`n").trimend()| %{
            for($i=0; $i -le $_.length; $i+=$width){
                if(($i+$width) -le $_.length){ 
                    "$indent"+$_.substring($i, $width)
                }else{
                    "$indent"+$_.substring($i, $_.length - $i)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

'##  Get-Process'
Indent-ConsoleOutput ((get-process)[0..5]|format-table) 4
''
'## Log Stye Output'
Indent-ConsoleOutput ((get-process)[0..5]|format-table) "    $(Get-Date) "
```

Comment: This is much better

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
 function Indent-ConsoleOutput($output, $indent=4){
    if(!($output -eq $null)){
        if(!( $indent -is [string])){
            $indent = ''.PadRight($indent)
        }
        $width = (Get-Host).UI.RawUI.BufferSize.Width - $indent.length
        ($output| out-string).trim().replace( "`r", "").split("`n").trimend()| %{
            for($i=0; $i -le $_.length; $i+=$width){
                if(($i+$width) -le $_.length){ 
                    "$indent"+$_.substring($i, $width)
                }else{
                    "$indent"+$_.substring($i, $_.length - $i)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

'##  Get-Process'
    Indent-ConsoleOutput ((get-process)[0..5]|format-table) 4
''
'## Log Stye Output'
    Indent-ConsoleOutput ((get-process)[0..5]|format-table) "    $(Get-Date) "
```